# Navigate to a component on different module on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular

I have 2 different modules, one is common UI module in which I have sso-Button Component, and other one is SSO Module, in which I have initiatesso Component.

There is a button in sso-button component, if click that button, it should redirect to initiatesso component.

I have tried following code.

Module: CommonUI Module
Sso-button.component.html:

```
<button class="logo-button" (click)="alert()" style="position:absolute;"> 
</button>
```

Sso-button.component.ts:

```
  public alert() {
    alert("");
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`initiatesso`);    
   }
```

Module: SSO Module

sso.module.ts:

```
export const ssoRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'initiatesso',
    component: InitiatessoComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    RouterModule.forChild(ssoRoutes),    
  ],
  declarations: [InitiatessoComponent],
  exports: [InitiatessoComponent]
})
export class SsoModule { }
```

initiatesso.component.html

```
 initiatesso works!
```

initiatesso.component.ts

```
export class InitiatessoComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

But on the button click I am not able to redirect to the initiatesso page, not sure where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Did you add SSOModule under imports in your UIModule?

Comment: URL should be absolute and start with '/'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UI module you need to import your SsoModule

So your code would look like this

```js
    @NgModule({
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        SsoModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(mainRoutes)
      ]
```

Then in your main routing you need to add your sso routing

```js
export const mainRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'initiatesso',
    component: InitiatessoComponent
  }
];
```

And change your SSOModule code into this

```js
export const ssoRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: InitiatessoComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    RouterModule.forChild(ssoRoutes),    
  ],
  declarations: [InitiatessoComponent],
  exports: [InitiatessoComponent]
})
export class SsoModule { }
```

RouterModule.forChild is use when you have sub route for the module like so you only need to define sub route in Route module for your SSO module like

```js
export const ssoRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: InitiatessoComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'abc',
    component: InitiatessoABCComponent
  }
];
```

> module/abc/

So now you can use

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl(`initiatesso`);
```

Please let me know if you need any help